# How to Print QR code in thermal printer in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, thermal-printer

---

In android, i am trying to develop an app that needs to print QR code using thermal printer (NGX). I think , its not being decoded properly, and i am unable to fix this problem.

*** [Details of Thermal printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auI9m.jpg)

[And i am getting output just like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md4xG.jpg)

> QR printing method

```
private void printQRCode() {
        int QRCODE_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 255;
        int QRCODE_IMAGE_WIDTH = 255;
        String finalQR = "";

        QRCodeWriter qrWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
        try {
            Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hints = new Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel>();
            hints.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrWriter.encode(finalQR,
                    BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                    QRCODE_IMAGE_WIDTH,
                    QRCODE_IMAGE_HEIGHT, hints);

            int bitMatrixWidth = bitMatrix.getWidth();

            int bitMatrixHeight = bitMatrix.getHeight();

            int[] pixels = new int[bitMatrixWidth * bitMatrixHeight];

            for (int y = 0; y < bitMatrixHeight; y++) {
                int offset = y * bitMatrixWidth;

                for (int x = 0; x < bitMatrixWidth; x++) {

                    pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ?
                            getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary) : getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                }
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

            bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, 255, 0, 0, bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight);

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.qr);

            Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getConfig());
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Matrix(), null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 94, 94, null); //34x34
            //canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 86, 86, null); //42x42

            if (bmOverlay != null) {
                byte[] command = Utils.decodeBitmap(bmOverlay);
                outputStream.write(ALLINEA_CT); //This command should center my QR, but it's not working
                outputStream.write(command);
                outputStream.write(FEED_LINE);
                outputStream.write(FEED_LINE);
            }
        }catch (WriterException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> bitmap decoding : this method helps to decode bitmap,

```
public static byte[] decodeBitmap(Bitmap bmp){
        int bmpWidth = 255;
        int bmpHeight = 255;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); //binaryString list
        StringBuffer sb;


        int bitLen = bmpWidth / 8;
        int zeroCount = bmpWidth % 8;

        String zeroStr = "";
        if (zeroCount > 0) {
            bitLen = bmpWidth / 8 + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < (8 - zeroCount); i++) {
                zeroStr = zeroStr + "0";
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < bmpHeight; i++) {
            sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int j = 0; j < bmpWidth; j++) {
                int color = bmp.getPixel(j, i);

                int r = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
                int g = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
                int b = color & 0xff;

                // if color close to white，bit='0', else bit='1'
                if (r > 160 && g > 160 && b > 160)
                    sb.append("0");
                else
                    sb.append("1");
            }
            if (zeroCount > 0) {
                sb.append(zeroStr);
            }
            list.add(sb.toString());
        }

        List<String> bmpHexList = binaryListToHexStringList(list);
        String commandHexString = "1D763000";
        String widthHexString = Integer
                .toHexString(bmpWidth % 8 == 0 ? bmpWidth / 8
                        : (bmpWidth / 8 + 1));
        if (widthHexString.length() > 2) {
            Log.e("decodeBitmap error", " width is too large");
            return null;
        } else if (widthHexString.length() == 1) {
            widthHexString = "0" + widthHexString;
        }
        widthHexString = widthHexString + "00";

        String heightHexString = Integer.toHexString(bmpHeight);
        if (heightHexString.length() > 2) {
            Log.e("decodeBitmap error", " height is too large");
            return null;
        } else if (heightHexString.length() == 1) {
            heightHexString = "0" + heightHexString;
        }
        heightHexString = heightHexString + "00";

        List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<String>();
        commandList.add(commandHexString+widthHexString+heightHexString);
        commandList.addAll(bmpHexList);

        return hexList2Byte(commandList);
    }
```

> printer commands

```
public class PrinterCommands {
    public static final byte HT = 0x9;
    public static final byte LF = 0x0A;
    public static final byte CR = 0x0D;
    public static final byte ESC = 0x1B;
    public static final byte DLE = 0x10;
    public static final byte GS = 0x1D;
    public static final byte FS = 0x1C;
    public static final byte STX = 0x02;
    public static final byte US = 0x1F;
    public static final byte CAN = 0x18;
    public static final byte CLR = 0x0C;
    public static final byte EOT = 0x04;


    public static final byte[] INIT = {27, 64};
    public static byte[] FEED_LINE = {10};

    public static byte[] SELECT_FONT_A = {27, 33, 0};

    public static byte[] FONT_B = {0x1B, 0x4D, 0x01};
    public static byte[] ALLINEA_SX = {0x1B, 0x61, 0x00};
    public static byte[] ALLINEA_CT = {0x1B, 0x61, 0x01};
    public static byte[] ALLINEA_DX = {0x1B, 0x61, 0x02};
    public static byte[] GRASSETTO_ON = {0x1B, 0x47, 0x11};
    public static byte[] GRASSETTO_OFF = {0x1B, 0x47, 0x00};
    public static byte[] SET_6 = {0x1B, 0x52, 0x06};
    public static byte[] CODICI = {0x1B, 0x74, 0x13};
    public static byte[] EURO = {(byte) 0xD5};
    public static byte[] PALLINO = {(byte) 0x5B};
    public static byte[] FONT_3X = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x21};
    public static byte[] FONT_2X = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x11};
    public static byte[] FONT_1X = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x00};

    public static byte[] SET_BAR_CODE_HEIGHT = {29, 104, 100};
    public static byte[] PRINT_BAR_CODE_1 = {29, 107, 2};
    public static byte[] SEND_NULL_BYTE = {0x00};

    public static byte[] SELECT_PRINT_SHEET = {0x1B, 0x63, 0x30, 0x02};
    public static byte[] FEED_PAPER_AND_CUT = {0x1D, 0x56, 66, 0x00};

    public static byte[] SELECT_CYRILLIC_CHARACTER_CODE_TABLE = {0x1B, 0x74, 0x11};

    public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE = {0x1B, 0x2F, 33, (byte) 255, 3};
    public static byte[] SET_LINE_SPACING_24 = {0x1B, 0x33, 24};
    public static byte[] SET_LINE_SPACING_30 = {0x1B, 0x33, 30};

    public static byte[] TRANSMIT_DLE_PRINTER_STATUS = {0x10, 0x04, 0x01};
    public static byte[] TRANSMIT_DLE_OFFLINE_PRINTER_STATUS = {0x10, 0x04, 0x02};
    public static byte[] TRANSMIT_DLE_ERROR_STATUS = {0x10, 0x04, 0x03};
    public static byte[] TRANSMIT_DLE_ROLL_PAPER_SENSOR_STATUS = {0x10, 0x04, 0x04};



    public static final byte[] ESC_FONT_COLOR_DEFAULT = new byte[] { 0x1B, 'r',0x00 };
    public static final byte[] FS_FONT_ALIGN = new byte[] { 0x1C, 0x21, 1, 0x1B, 0x21, 1 };
    public static final byte[] ESC_ALIGN_LEFT = new byte[] { 0x1b, 'a', 0x00 };
    public static final byte[] ESC_ALIGN_RIGHT = new byte[] { 0x1b, 'a', 0x02 };
    public static final byte[] ESC_ALIGN_CENTER = new byte[] { 0x1b, 'a', 0x01 };
    public static final byte[] ESC_CANCEL_BOLD = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x45, 0 };


    /*********************************************/
    public static final byte[] ESC_HORIZONTAL_CENTERS = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x44, 20, 28, 00};
    public static final byte[] ESC_CANCLE_HORIZONTAL_CENTERS = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x44, 00 };
    /*********************************************/

    public static final byte[] ESC_ENTER = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x4A, 0x40 };
    public static final byte[] PRINTE_TEST = new byte[] { 0x1D, 0x28, 0x41 };

}
```

Comment: Any details about the printer? Their drivers and encoding vary and it might be helpful in finding your answer

Comment: I uploaded one more image, let me know if it is helpful or not.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh this might be an [end-of-lifetime product](http://www.ngxtechnologies.com/product-category/our-products/pos-printers/) (else it should be listed there) ...while you're most likely not switching it to graphical output. `SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE` appears to be the sequence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printing QR codes through an ESC/POS thermal printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577702/printing-qr-codes-through-an-esc-pos-thermal-printer)

Comment: @martin Zeitler , after adding "outputStream.write(PrinterCommands.SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE);" . its printing with BOLD NGX logo alongwith earlier output.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh you'd probably need to print it as raster bit-image. see [GS(L<fn=50>)](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=98)... and not the NV bit-image (which is the default header image, stored inside the printer, eg. for receipt logo images). even the name `SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE` hints for it being a mode-switching command.

Comment: I got the solution. Actually , i asked the solution from NGX comapny . Thank you all of you for being here to figure out the problem.

Comment: There is a dedicated Command set for printing Barcodes in ESC/POS, please download documentation.